# Change div height when at top of page - long delay? - Jquery

Tags: jquery

Sorry if this is the most basic of questions - I'm a total novice when it comes to jquery/javascript! I've had a look around for an answer to this but I dont really know what to search!

I want to have a fixed navigation bar that shortens if the user is not at the top of the page, this is working fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/2NW6u/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 10) {
            $('#headerContent').animate({paddingTop: '18px', paddingBottom:'18px'}, 300);
        } else {
            $('#headerContent').animate({padding: '0px'}, 300);
        }
    });

});
```

});

...but there is a considerable delay when I scroll to the top of the page, what is causing this and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the `scroll` event is fired multiple times and for each time it fires you queue a new animation..

You need to clear the queue each time (*by using [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop)*)..

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() < 10) {
    $('#headerContent').stop(true, false).animate({
        paddingTop: '18px',
        paddingBottom: '18px'
    }, 300);
} else {
    $('#headerContent').stop(true, false).animate({
        padding: '0px'
    }, 300);
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/2NW6u/4/

Comment: This works but giving render line bugs in chrome (webkit safari???). We have to set outline property to get rid of it: outline:1px solid transparent;  http://jsfiddle.net/2NW6u/10/

Comment: @roasted, it seems to work fine in my chrome (*v.26.0.1410.64*), but thanks for the suggestion that might help all that are having that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() < 10) {
    $('#headerContent').stop().animate({paddingTop: '18px', paddingBottom:'18px'},300);
} else {
    $('#headerContent').stop().animate({padding: '0px'}, 300);
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2NW6u/9/

Comment: I tried something like that but obviously the animation becomes very jumpy - what Id really like to do is apply the 300ms delay to only to the actual animation (the sliding effect) but have it start that instantly rather than waiting 300ms before starting then a further 300ms to increase the height... at least I assume thats whats happening!